# Providing guest users with full accounts vs only sessions (a.k.a. guest checkout)

Tags: database-design, web-applications, authentication

I'm working on a web application with JWT authentication (with token stored in cookie) and an SQL database. Upon loading, the frontend makes a request to the backend to determine whether the user is authenticated and who he is.

In order to make the app more convenient to use, I want to allow users to use most of the features without signing up (i.e. submitting email + password).

1. My currently preferred approach is to automatically create a proper account whenever the frontend makes that initial request without a valid authentication token and the user is immediately signed in, though the frontend pretends otherwise. When the user performs a sign in, the created account would be deleted and user would be signed in to their own account. Upon sign up, the user would become the owner of the guest account by setting an email and a password. The big advantage of this approach is, that, since the user always has a proper account with user id, all the APIs can keep the same logic for both guests and signed up users. The only downside I see, is that the email field in the users table would have to contain a random UUID to satisfy the unique constraint on the email field while the user is a guest.
2. The other approach would be to create a separate table "sessions" and return a session id stored in a cookie to guest users. Upon sign up, the entry in the users table would be created and all the information attached to the session copied into tables attached to the users table. This would require creating a separate logic for guests and signed up users for each API.

Neither approach is completely clean, the first one essentially creates fake user accounts for guest users while the second one complicates the logic in every API function, having to decide where to store information depending on whether the user is authenticated.

Is there an alternative approach that's better?
What are the issues that could arise if I go with the first approach?

Edit: A third approach would be to add user_proxys table and associate with it all information regardless of whether user is authenticated or not. It would have an optional key to the users table which would be set upon signing up. The JWT token would need to reference an id from this table. This seems to be clean but maybe unnecessarily complicated compared to approach 1.

Edit 2: [This question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/369276/352890) is about a similar problem but in the context of an e-commerce application. The accepted answer suggests approach 2 but in that case they only need to worry about orders and addresses while I have about a dozen interrelated tables that need to be filled in by both guest and signed up users.

Comment: *"the email field in the users table would have to contain a random UUID to satisfy the unique constraint on the email field"*  - This rather depends upon the database - a unique constraint should not normally prevent you from having multiple `null` values.    Are you sure you're not trying to solve a problem that doesn't exist?

Comment: For how long do you intend to store the information collected in the sessions tables or for the fake user accounts? How would it affect you if your anonymous visitors routinely wipe their cookies and create new fake accounts/session entries?

Comment: What would be the effect is someone first does a lot of activity without logging in and then logs in into their existing account? How much trouble is it for you to merge the guest account with the proper account versus what is the user experience if the user loses the data associated with the actions done under the guest account?

Comment: @BenCottrell Currently, I'm using the email in the sub field of the JWT token so it can't be null. But you're right, if I replace the email with user id in the token I could just leave email null.

Comment: @BartvanIngenSchenau I would track last access and delete accounts/sessions not accessed for a couple months. There is a lot of data the user can enter before sign up, including the upload of pictures etc. So copying that information is quite an effort. Guest user shouldn't loose data unless they delete cookies. If they log in, the guest account becomes unaccessible but I'm not worried about it, I expect returning users to sign in instead of using the guest account.

Comment: I'm pretty confident that approach 1 would work, however, I haven't found much information about it so I'm curious whether there might be problems I've overlooked.